Call Power Automate HTTP Request Trigger in Power BI for data source
In Power Automate I have a HTTP Request Trigger automation set up that generates some data and returns the JSON.
When this Power Automate flow is set to 'Anyone' for "Who Can Trigger The Flow", I can successfully connect to this data source in Power BI through Web.Contents(...).
When I update my Power Automate flow to 'Any user in my tenant' for "Who Can Trigger The Flow", the the data source query in Power BI asks for credentials.
When I try the "Organizational account" option, I get the error "We were unable to connect because this credential type isn't supported for this resource. Please choose another credential type".
When I try 'Windows' or 'Basic' I get the error "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again."
In what way should I be setting up Power BI to connect to this Power Automate flow?
